# ARM Cortex M0, shift buffer, bitlevel

Tags: cortex-m

I need a fast shift buffer bitwise on Cortex M0.
It's possible using inline asm to get address of buffer

```
static uint8_t tmp[30];
```

and rotate all to right with 1 position (carry)?

I can't find proper guidance for gcc inline asm on M0. On PIC16,18 Microchip,
I'd simply use rotate with (default) carry, one instruction next another for each buffer (memory address)

```
rlf   buff+0,F
rlf   buff+1,F
rlf   buff+2,F
etc
```

It's possible on M0?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GCC, to get the address of your buffer, use:

```
ldr r0, =#tmp
```

and further you can rotate with the .asm instruction:

```
RORS {Rd,} Rm, Rs
```

Use your micro brand programming manual for details of this instruction.